# What are the possible alternate title sequences?

Tags: nintendo-wii, mario-kart-wii

I recently got gold in every Grand Prix race in Mario Kart Wii, and now there are various opening title sequences. Some of the alternate sequences are Mario saying something slightly different, and some feature different characters. What are all of the possible openings?

<sub>And by title sequence, I mean the screen where Mario says "Mario Kart, Wii!" and it tells you to press the A button to continue.</sub>

Comment: I think it is sad that I've never noticed the title screens are different.  I must be in too much of a hurry to start the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this video](http://revver.com/video/839394/mario-kart-alternate-title-screens/), there are **7 alternate title screens**.

1. Mario with crossed arms, saying "Mario Kart Wii!"
2. Mario driving in his kart saying "Mario Kart, whee-ee!"
3. Luigi saying "Mario Kart Wii! (with the man Luigi!)"
4. Luigi in the same pose saying "Luigi Kart Wii!"
5. Bowser laughing maniacally
6. Peach driving her bike saying "Mario Kart Wii!"
7. Peach in the same pose saying "Peach Kart Wii!"

Comment: I actually have no idea what Luigi is saying in the third title screen - if anybody can figure it out, feel free to edit it in. :)